# useEffect in custom hook is not being called when dependency from another custom hook changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following custom hook which returns a state and the setter for it.

```
export function useProvideAuth() {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>(
        "noToken"
    );

    const setAuth = (newToken: string) => {

        // Note: I have not included the full logic in this function for simplicity's sake

        setAccessToken(newToken);
    };
    return { accessToken, setAccessToken: setAuth };
};
```

I am then using this custom hook inside another custom hook. The `accessToken` value from the previous custom hook is used as a dependency for a `useEffect`.

```
export function useMyUserDetails() {
    const { accessToken } = useProvideAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Does something

        // This useEffect never gets called when the accessToken changes
    }, [accessToken]);
}
```

However, the `useEffect` in the above hook is never executed when the `accessToken` changes, it only executes once initially.

Also, I should mention that in the component in which I am calling the `setAccessToken` setter, the `accessToken` **does** update in that component, however in my custom hook the `accessToken` doesn't update for some reason and so it doesn't trigger the `useEffect`.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the auth hook outside your user details hook since you haven't used the setAccessToken in your user details  hook. If so, this is to be expected.

Comment: @nullptr I am calling setAccessToken in a whole other component. When I call setAccessToken there, why does it not also cause the useEffect to retrigger in my custom hook since the accessToken has changed? How can I possibly make this work :(

If you want you can post as an answer, I will mark it as a solution :)

Comment: @nullptr Do I need to use context instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use context or some other global state solution if you want your accessToken(and its "change events") to be available globally. The problem with your code is that each instance of your user details hooks and components will have a different copy of the state. So, basically, it is a local state, even if your auth hook is used in multiple places. I would go for something like this:

```
const AuthContext = createContext('');


function App() {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>("");
  const setAuth = (newToken: string) => {
    setAccessToken(newToken);
  };
  ...
  return <AuthProvider.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>...</AuthProvider.Provider>
}
```